# Find the sum of previous count occurrences per unique ID in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a history of customer IDs and purchase IDs where no customer has ever bought the same product. However, for each purchase ID (which is unique), how can I find out the number of times the customer has made a previous purchase

I have tried using groupby() and sort_values()

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_cust': [1,2,1,3,2,4,1],                   
                  'id_purchase': ['20A','143C','99B','78R','309D','90J','78J']})
df.sort_values(by='id_cust')
df.groupby('id_cust')['id_purchase'].cumcount()
```

This is what I expect:

```
  id_cust   id_purchase value
  1              20A        1
  2              143C       1
  1              99B        2
  3              78R        1
  2              3097D      2
  4              900J       1
  1              78J        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `cumcount()` on the `id_cust` column since the `id_purchase` is unique:

```
df['value']=df.groupby('id_cust')['id_cust'].cumcount()+1
print(df)
```

---

```
   id_cust id_purchase  value
0        1         20A      1
1        2        143C      1
2        1         99B      2
3        3         78R      1
4        2        309D      2
5        4         90J      1
6        1         78J      3
```